# How to set global variables for different GUIs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to do something like this: a program where at the beginning some data is initialized. Then I open other GUIs where I show some graphics from these data.

[image]

[image]

Is there any possible way to set some global variables for different GUIs? If not, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you pass the handle of the first GUI to the second, you can access all the properties of GUI#1 from GUI#2 (and vice versa, since the GUI creation method returns the handle to GUI#2).

Alternatively, you can collect the data you want to visualize (as well as the handles of the GUIs) in a handle object, which means it is passed by reference and thus available everywhere.

Finally, you can, of course, create global variables - at the beginning of any function that would like to access these variables you have to declare them as `global var1, var2, var3`.